# Errore: list indices must be integers or slices, not str... how can i fix it?

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to run this program, which takes words and credentials, creates a class for each of them. Finally for each class it cycles the words in a function:

```
usernameDati = [] 
credenzaliDati = [] 
listaUtenti = []

# Importa le parole with open('parole.json') as fileParole:
    filePar = json.load(fileParole)
    usernameDati = filePar

# Importa le credenziali with open('utenti.txt') as fileUtenti:
    for stringa in fileUtenti:
        username, password = stringa.strip().split(":")  # Dividi la stringa in username e password
        listaUtenti.append((username, password))

# Crea le istanze e aggiungile alla lista credenzaliDati for username, password in listaUtenti:
    credenzaliDati.append(Utente(username, password, usernameDati))

while True:
    errore_trovato = False  # Flag per indicare se è stata trovata un'eccezione
    
    for i in range(0, len(credenzaliDati)):
        try:
            credenzaliDati[i].checkUsername()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Si è verificato un errore:", type(e).__name__)
            print("Messaggio di errore:", str(e))
            errore_trovato = True  # Imposta il flag su True
            break
    
    if errore_trovato:
        break
```

and I don't understand why this error is returned to the exeption where I check `credenzaliData[i].checkUsername()`

```
Si è verificato un errore: TypeError
Messaggio di errore: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Instead of catching and printing the exception why not let the exception raise as the full traceback will be more helpful